# How to multiply elements in the list in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I've found answers that tackle the question of how to multiply with the element value, but what concerns me is how to make copies of the element itself. I have:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
x = 3
b = []
```

I tried:

```
b.append(a * x)
```

But that gives me:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

and I need:

```
b = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Please note I'm a programming novice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to copy the list and not a reference to the list, you can't use `*`.

```
b = [a[:] for i in range(x)]
```

(`a[:]` creates a copy of the list.)